# Values of WCHAN in ps

Tags: kernel, ps

What does the WCHAN (waiting channel) mean exactly? what can be its value and what those values represents? I tried to find them but got nothing.

Comment: related: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/404854/in-ps-l-what-does-wchan-stext-mean

Answer (score 3):

From [`man ps`](http://manpages.ubuntu.com/manpages/trusty/en/man1/ps.1.html#contenttoc10), section `Standard Format Specifiers`:

```
nwchan     WCHAN     address of the kernel function where the process
                     is sleeping (use wchan if you want the kernel
                     function name).  Running tasks will display a
                     dash ('-') in this column.
wchan      WCHAN     name of the kernel function in which the process
                     is sleeping, a "-" if the process is running, or
                     a "*" if the process is multi-threaded and ps is
                     not displaying threads.
```

As can be seen, they are the kernel functions currently being used by the process. Further:

```
-n namelist
      Set namelist file.  Identical to N.  The namelist file is needed
      for a proper WCHAN display, and must match the current Linux
      kernel exactly for correct output.  Without this option, the
      default search path for the namelist is:

              $PS_SYSMAP
              $PS_SYSTEM_MAP
              /proc/*/wchan
              /boot/System.map-$(uname -r)
              /boot/System.map
              /lib/modules/$(uname -r)/System.map
              /usr/src/linux/System.map
              /System.map
```

You can inspect `/boot/System.map-$(uname -r)` on Ubuntu for a list of functions:

```
$ sudo head /boot/System.map-$(uname -r)
0000000000000000 D __per_cpu_start
0000000000000000 D irq_stack_union
0000000000000000 A xen_irq_disable_direct_reloc
0000000000000000 A xen_save_fl_direct_reloc
00000000000001e0 A kexec_control_code_size
0000000000004000 d exception_stacks
0000000000009000 D gdt_page
000000000000a000 D espfix_waddr
000000000000a008 D espfix_stack
000000000000a020 D cpu_info
```

Comment: when I type "ps -elf" i found WCHAN column saying different values like: poll_s , smpboo,rescue,hrtime,worker,unix_s,wait. What those stats mean?

Comment: @ChiragAcharya so? Did you expect them to contain the same value?

Comment: I actually wanted to know what those values mean?

Comment: @ChiragAcharya can't you read the answer? They're names of functions.

Comment: they are names of functions but i want to know meaning of them.. lets say about "wait" it means that process is placed into wait state because it might not be getting resources. like wise for all other states.

Comment: @ChiragAcharya there are hundreds of them. You'll have to read the kernel source for that. I'm not going to do that for you.

Comment: @ChiragAcharya and I don't think that's what wait means.

Comment: that's what i wanted to know.. i was just assuming.

Comment: Thats fine if you don't want to tell me meaning of hundred of them but can you give me any source where i can read them!!

Comment: @ChiragAcharya as I said, read the kernel source. You can get sites like http://lxr.free-electrons.com/ to search for functions. And use `-o wchan=WIDE-WCHAN-COLUMN` with `ps` so that you get the full function name.

Comment: thanx i would go through them

Answer (score 1):

Note that this answer is mostly obsolete: you should never need a namelist or `System.map` anymore. `ps` in `procps-ng` reads `/proc/${pid}/wchan` directly, instead of reading the 30th field (wchan) out of `/proc/${pid}/stat` and decoding it against a symbol map file.

In fact, some kernels may set the wchan field of `/proc/${pid}/stat` to 1 instead of a real value in order to hide the details of kernel address space layout randomization.

(I'm hitting some odd issues with wchan on Fedora 32 though, see [fedora bug 1879450](https://bugzilla.redhat.com/show_bug.cgi?id=1879450)).